# Why did I read message from queue whereas the sequence is not correct?

Tags: msmq

I encountered an issue where sometimes the `lookupid` will jump when I read message from queue by `lookupID`.

The process is that I will use `MQ_LOOKUP_PEEK_FIRST` as the action parameter to read first message, and then use `MQ_LOOKUP_PEEK_NEXT` to read subsequent message until the queue is empty, then I will start using `MQ_LOOKUP_PEEK_FIRST` to read the first message.

The problem is sometimes I may read a message with `lookupid` which is bigger than the `lookupid` in the next message. How could it happen?

Comment: Can you post some code to help us help you?

Comment: The codes are too much to put here. Just wondering if it is possible in theroy this could happen?

Comment: Could it be that one message is of a higher priority? (I can't quite remember if MSMQ has priorties, but I think it does, it's possible that I'm wrong).

Comment: the priority is actually same, have done some research and found MSMQ can't guarantee the order of message, that's how MQ works.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the link below, looks like it proves what I think that MQ message could be out of order.
http://www.ms-news.net/f2437/how-can-messages-appear-out-order-non-transacational-messages-11964070.html